# editor showing errors with Aptana Studio 3 after update

Tags: python, aptana

I have used Aptana Studio 3 for the programming of python for quite a while and never had problems. But after the update today (the version now is 3.5.0.201401092130-09012014213131), the editor stopped recognizing a lot of code (it marks functions like `len, int, float` and even things like `None` or `True` as errors).

I still can run all my programs without any problems so i figured that this must be an issue with an editor. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: What language are you using? Have you installed plugins?  Have you checked for more recent version of those plugins?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 with PyDev. I have checked for updates and the program didn't find anything.

Comment: For all of Eclipse's strengths there are some odd and persisting quirks.  Have you tried making a new workspace and copying all of your source code into it?

Comment: I am using the standalone version of Aptana Studio and not the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Aptana is built on top of Eclipse and under the hood it is pretty much the same thing.  My concern here is the workspace/project metadata files which are created on the older version are no longer compatible with the newer version for some reason (usually `.eclipse` or `.project` inside your workspace folders on *nix or hidden folders in windows).  The code that handles the creation of those files is likely the same in both Aptana/Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, but this workaround worked for me. After reverting to a previous version (3.4.1 in my case), the behavior I described above still persisted. But after I switched between the PyDev and the Web perspective a couple times, the editor went back to the normal behavior (the perspective switching didn't do the trick for version 3.5).

When I talk about version reverting, I don't mean the build in option (I tried it, but it just showed an error). I deleted the Aptana Studio 3 installation folder and downloaded the 3.4.1 version from [this website](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version).