# Last stable release for APTANA Studio for PHP is 3.3

Tags: php, xdebug, aptana3

I use `aptana studio 3.3.1` for long time, and I try to install new release.
For each the problem is the same...

In debug mode (PHP env), **the editor do not display the source code of current running line**...

```
3.4.2
3.6.0
3.6.1
3.7.2
```

So I reinstall `3.3.1` that run correctly.

Do you know if there is a fix to get last release (for `php 8`) and running debug correctly ?

Best regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064605/editor-showing-errors-with-aptana-studio-3-after-update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591492/aptana-studio-3-not-showing-themes